# Pagination doesn't work with extendable layouts in 11ty ( eleventy )

Tags: javascript, layout, static, nunjucks, eleventy

**Describe the bug**
When I extend nunjuck layout, pagination doesn't work

**To Reproduce**

```
{% extends "layouts/default.njk" %}

---
pagination:
  data: categories
  size: 1
  alias: category
eleventyComputed:
  title: "{{ category.name }}"
---

{% block content %}

    {%- for category in categories %}
    
        <h1>{{ category.name }}</h1>
    
    {% endfor -%}

{% endblock %}
```

**Expected behavior**
It should generate the categories pages

**Screenshots**
the result file is empty

**Environment:**

- OS and Version: Windows 10
- Eleventy Version 0.12.1

**Additional context**
Add any other context about the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Front matter needs to be, well, front. It has to be on top. Try moving the extends above the block. (But still below the front matter.)